# get quantity of enabled and disabled products by sku

Tags: product, collection, stock, inventory, maintenance

I am handed a list of skus from a black box.  I need to return a collection containing the quantities of all skus within the array.

```
function fun1($arrayOfSkus){
    .....
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1,'left');   
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('in'=>arrayOfSkus))->addAttributeToSort('sku','ASC');
    return $collection;
}
```

The above works perfectly for what i'm trying to achieve, however, it does NOT return anything for skus that are of products that are disabled, any solutions?

Comment: Could you tell me what "echo (string) $collection->getSelect();" returns?

Comment: @MartijnSchot I found a solution.  The problem was that disabled products are now included within the flat products table. I'll post it in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not entirely magento friendly this is the only (maybe) way to retrieve disabled product quantities when flat product collections are enabled.

```
function fun1($arrayOfSkus){
    // format components array to string
    $SkuString = $this->format($arrayOfSkus);

    // prepare sql query to find all (enabled and disabled) product quantities by sku
    $componentQuantityQuery = "SELECT k.`qty`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity` i
        RIGHT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item k ON i.entity_id = k.item_id
        WHERE i.`sku` IN ($SkuString)
        GROUP BY i.`sku`
        ORDER BY i.`sku` ASC";

    // fetch disabled and enabled quantities
    return $componentQuantities = $connection->fetchAll($componentQuantityQuery);
}

/**
* format array to SQL statement
* @param $array
* @return string
*/
private function format($array)
{
    // initialize variable
    $formattedArray = array();

    //for each element
    foreach ($array as $string) {
        //append quotes
        $formattedArray[] = "'" . $string . "'";
    }

    //convert formatted elements to string and return
    $formattedString = implode(',', $formattedArray);

    return $formattedString;
}
```